# Where should this question regarding the viability of new TLDs go?

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

I asked [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/147646/396) that was closed, migrated, then rejected.

> Suppose I were to purchase a new domain of `.financial`, hence my
>   email would be `chris@company.financial`.
>
> **Question**
>
> - What assurances are there that the root name server, the registrar infrastructure will be in place for X years?
> - What financial backing exists to insure their operation for those X years?
> - Solve for X.  ;)

In my perspective this has implications with fault tolerance, SSL certificates, spoofing, and risks involved in a change-of-control of a TLD.

**Risk scenario**

Suppose china buys all the non profitable TLDs, such as `.financial`. My hard links wouldn't have the same security guarantees as first offered. DNSSec, DANE Certificates and more will make the most prudent end user unaware of the change in security.

**Question**

Where should this question go?

Comment: If you had a (proposed) contract of sale it might lead to some questions that would work on Law.SE, such as "Does this contract encumber ownership of the TLD and would that prevent sale/transfer of the TLD to a foreign entity?"  You'd want to have the actual terms of the agreement before asking, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think Webmasters.SE would be the best fit. There are a lot of domain registration questions on there and I would expect experts in this field to be lurking there.

Answer (score 0):

Of your three questions, I can't imagine any would work anywhere on Stack Exchange.

1. no-one gives assurances on this
2. only speculation possible
3. what?

There are no actual real answerable quests there.